# How to run weather-app-demo from Trigger.io

Tags: android, trigger.io, forge

I got Weather app demo from the below Github link. I don't know `how to import this into Eclipse?` or `How to import and run into Trigger.io Toolkit?`

https://github.com/trigger-corp/weather-app-demo/

Answer (score 1):

The documentation contains a tutorial on how to get started with Trigger and setup this app https://trigger.io/docs/current/getting_started/tutorial/tutorial-1.html

Using Trigger does not involve eclipse (unless you are writing a native module), to use that code in an app in the Toolkit, create a new app and replace its src folder with the contents of that repository, making sure to leave the apps identity.json.